# Python For Loop Output Integer

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

This for loop should take the entered input and convert the character into an integer.

```
input = a
output = []
for char in input:
     num = ord(char) - 96
     output.append(num)
```

The problem is that at the end the output is equal to "[1]".

```
>>>print(output)
>>>[1]
```

I need it to be an int to multiply it.

Comment: Then why append it to a list?

Comment: Why is `output` a list to begin with?

Comment: Is that first line supposed to be `input = "a"`? BTW, you should not use `input` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `input` function.

Comment: To [retrieve an item from a list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), use its index `n = output[0]`.

Comment: is your input a string containing just digits?

Answer (score 0):

The **ord()** method returns an integer representing Unicode code point for the given Unicode character.

In your case, you have your input as 'a', which is represented by the number: 97

```
>>> print ord('a')
97
```

Hence, when you subtract 96 from 97, you get 1.

It already is an int ....

```
>>> if type(ord('a')) is int:
...     print 'is int'
... else:
...     pass
...
is int
```

Lastly, if you want to multiply it, change your operator from ' **-** ' to ' * ' ...

```
>>> input = 'B'
>>> print ord(input) 
66

>>> output = []
>>> for char in input:
...     num = ord(char) * 2
...     print num
132
```

Comment: I _think_ the OP wants to do arithmetic on the result of `ord(char) - 96`.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = a
output = []
total = 0;
for char in input:
    num = int(char)
    total = (total*10)+num
```

My answer assumes that the input is a number but in string format and that you want to iterate over it. Because in case it is a small number you can do:

```
int(input)
```

I would need more explanation to clarify my answer. Hope this helps.